# Parámetros en clases privadas

Tags: c++

soy estudiante de primero de ingeniería informática y tengo una duda, estoy creando una clase ruleta que va a tener los colores rojo y negro para los números pares e impares respectivamente, para ello voy a hacer un array para cada uno, pero el numero 0, en la ruleta es verde, entonces como es un valor estático, es decir, no va a cambiar, ¿puedo poner?:
private:
int verde=0;
Gracias

Comment: La pregunta obvia es ... ¿ has probado a hacer lo que dices ? ¿ Te apareció algún error ? Porque probar eso es **muy fácil** :-)

Answer (score 0):

Exactamente no se que el lo que se intenta en tu programa, pero te dejo este código, por si te sirve:

```
#define VERDE   0
#define ROJO    1
#define NEGRO   2
#define MAX_VALORES_RULETA 36+1     // 36 (rojo y negro) y uno verde

class Ruleta
{
    int valores[MAX_VALORES_RULETA];
public:
    Ruleta();
    ~Ruleta();
public:
    void print();
};

Ruleta::Ruleta()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_VALORES_RULETA; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
        {
            valores[i] = VERDE;
        }
        else
        {
            if((i&1) == 0)
                valores[i] = ROJO;
            else
                valores[i] = NEGRO;
        }
    }
}
Ruleta::~Ruleta()
{
}
void Ruleta::print()
{
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_VALORES_RULETA; i++)
    {
        switch(valores[i])
        {
            case VERDE:
                printf("%2d: VERDE\n", i);
                break;
            case ROJO:
                printf("%2d: ROJO\n", i);
                break;
            case NEGRO:
                printf("%2d: NEGRO\n", i);
                break;
        }
    }
}
void main()
{
    Ruleta r;

    r.print();
}
```

Comment: Solo busque ayudar a detectar, cuales son verde, rojo ó negro, despues el usuario sabrá como utilizarlo.

Answer (score 0):

Tu quieres crear un array para gestionar los colores, bien, podemos tener, por ejemplo, algo tal que:

```
//                         VERDE     ROJO      NEGRO
int const colores[3] = { 0x00FF00, 0xFF0000, 0x000000 };
```

Aunque desde C++11 también podemos tener esto:

```
//                                    VERDE     ROJO      NEGRO
std::array<int,3> const colores = { 0x00FF00, 0xFF0000, 0x000000 };
```

En efecto el algoritmo tiene que gestionar 3 colores, bueno, para cosas así se pensaron los enumerados:

```
enum Colores
{
  CL_VERDE,
  CL_ROJO,
  CL_NEGRO
};
```

Y ahora a cohexionarlo todo:

```
int GetColor(Color color)
{
  return colores[static_cast<int>(color)];
}

int GetColor(int numero)
{
  Color color;
  if( numero == 0 )
    color = CL_VERDE;
  else if( numero % 2 == 0 )
    color = CL_ROJO;
  else
    color = CL_NEGRO;

  return GetColor(color);
}

int color0 = GetColor(12); // color ROJO
int color1 = GetColor(7);  // color NEGRO
int color2 = GetColor(0);  // color VERDE
```

Y ya está, esta lógica la puedes encapsular dentro de la clase `Ruleta` si así lo deseas... esa parte corre de tu cuenta que te vendrá bien practicar.

La idea de tener dos funciones `GetColor` es porque en algún momento puede que necesites recuperar un color en concreto:

```
int color = GetColor(VERDE);
```

Por otro lado, desde C++11 es posible darle un tipado fuerte a los enumerados. Esta característica ayuda, desde mi punto de vista, a que el código sea más seguro y legible:

```
enum class Colores
{
  Verde,
  Rojo,
  Negro
};

int GetColor(int numero)
{
  Color color;
  if( numero == 0 )
    color = Color::Verde;
  else if( numero % 2 == 0 )
    color = Color::Rojo;
  else
    color = Color::Negro;

  return GetColor(color);
}
```